# Is there any program that will allow me to switch DNS providers?

Tags: windows-7, dns, network-adapter

Is there any program that will allow me to switch my DNS providers with out having to go through the network adapter settings in Windows 7?

Comment: This will not change your DNS, but is a handy DNS tool...http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would not go through your adapter settings. It's the TCP/IP settings that contain DNS in my experience.

You can set DNS for a connection using the Windows netsh tool:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.200
```

Sample taken from http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm.

If you need to, you can very easily make this into a batch file you can run using the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DNS Changer](http://code.google.com/p/dnschanger/).

> Sometimes, you need to change DNS
>   Server and you make some step to
>   finish it. With DNS Changer, you can
>   change DNS easy and faster.
>
> This program require dot.NET Framework
>   3.5 to run.